# Setting Default Applications for Opening files without extension on Mac OS X(Such as Vagrantfile's)

Tags: macos, vagrant, text-editor, file-extension

I'd like to see if there is a way to set the Default Application to open a file without extensions on Mac OS X.

Let me give an example-

Anyone who has used Vagrant has seen a Vagrantfile. It has no extension. If anything, it could be considered a Ruby script, but it isn't named like one. When clicking on "Get Info" the Kind is listed as a TextEdit Document. TextEdit is actually the last thing I want opening it, since it has actually added fancy quotations in the past in the place of standard quotations from code editors/IDE's, rending my code useless. If I use the "Change All" command inside the "Get Info" window, an error will come up telling me it doesn't have enough information to change the default Application for similar files. It will set the default application for that Vagrantfile, but not all of them. I end up having to set them all in a folder by folder, file by file basis.

I'd like to make it so that every time I open a Vagrantfile, my code editor of choice (in this case, Brackets), is used to open it. There are other examples as well. Some config files and scripts also have this problem, but Vagrantfile was the easiest example, and the one I come across most. I can't change all TextEdit documents to open in my code editor, because then regular TextEdit files like ReadMe's and such will open in my code editor, slowing me down by opening my IDE/editor when I don't need it loaded up.

So does anyone have any ideas? Is there any way to write a script that tells the OS that anytime I open a file called "Vagrantfile" or "default" or "config",etc. to open it in my code editor of choice?

Thanks guys,

P.J.

Comment: There might be a way to set all type `text/plain` to open in your editor of choice but i dont think there is going to be a way to associate `Vagrantfile`, `config` without somehow setting its mime type to something specific. Without an extension the OS will fall back to the file's mime-type.

Comment: Do you think there is a way I could change the current MIME type? As of right now the OS believes its a TextEdit file, so could I just have it believe its a plain text file, or even a shell script?